# Automatic Alcohol Dispenser: What is the Resistor's value for transistor?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, resistors, circuit-design

I wanted to assemble the circuit below
[image: schematic]

Link: https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Automatic-Alcohol-Dispenser-No-Arduino-Needed/

I read about the transistor's datasheet and I found out that the current base is -3A max rating. These are my following questions:

1. Why does it need a 1k ohm resistor? Since voltage is only 5v
2. What would happen if I remove the 1k ohm resistor?
3. How to compute the value of the resistor for the transistor's base? I saw formulas in google but still confuses me.

Your answer and explanation is gladly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Actually, TIP32C is a poor example of a "general-purpose transistor" in this application. You're only giving it about 4.3 mA of base current, and its gain is only about 25, which means that your motor can't draw more than about 100 mA. The transistor could handle as much as 1A base current, but that would be too much for the sensor. The resistor limits the current to something the sensor can handle.

Comment: What will I do in order for the motor to draw at least 100mA? Replace Transistor?

Comment: How much current is the sensor designed to output?

Comment: I guess very low because the supply current for the sensor is only 20mA.